# Property implementation must have its declaration in the Interface 'xxx' error

Tags: iphone, debugging

Im a new app coder and I keep getting the error below:

[image: error]

I have searched and searched the internet but just cannot find anything on this problem?

Comment: Or even - don't synthesize your properties. The newer versions of Xcode do this for you.

Comment: Typo based problem - voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

Spelling in your property declaration - ouput instead of output.